# Navigate to real folder after searching

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I do search in explorer for particular file and get list of results. In case I enter to one of results I get into folder with required files, but path name starts with words "Search Results ..". How to navigate to real folder with required files?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're viewing the search results, right click on the file/folder of interest en press *Open file location*:

[image]